# Difference between "hwplug" and "hw"

Tags: audio, alsa, wolfson-audio-card

This is `aplay -l` output from Raspberry Pi:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 0: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA]
  Subdevices: 8/8
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
  Subdevice #7: subdevice #7
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 1: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: RPiCirrus [RPi-Cirrus], device 0: WM5102 AiFi wm5102-aif1-0 []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I try to record audio from Cirrus audio card with the `arecord` alsa command:

```
arecord -f S16_LE -c2  -D hw:1,0 -r 44100  ~/Desktop/test.wav
```

Should I set `-D` flag as

```
-D hw:1,0
```

or

```
-D plughw:1,0
```

and what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`hw` accesses the hardware device directly.

`plughw` inserts sample rate and format conversion plugins, if needed.